# How to use grep or awk to extract specific block from a file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a sample data in a log file

> NODE-ID> command1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> NODE-ID> command2
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> NODE-ID> command3
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

I have a file which is generated by sequential commands. I am not sure how can i extract data from the log file

suppose if I need to extract data from file

> NODE-ID> command1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

what is the best way to do so ? I have most my script written in shell script, I can use awk or sed. Please suggest

Comment: Can you give more information about your data format? Are the location and number of blank lines consistent? Are the number of entries (ie lines) in each text block the same? If there's a consistent data format it would be helpful to know the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'sub BEGIN { $/="NODE-ID> "; } { if (/^command1/) { s:$/$::; print "$/$_"; }}'
```

Not sed/awk, but...it works.

This *is* awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="NODE-ID> "; } /^command1/ { print RS $0; }'
```

And inspired by CodeGnome, I add a sed option:

```
sed -n '/^NODE-ID> command1/,/^NODE-ID> / { /^NODE-ID> command1/ { p; d; }; /^NODE-ID> /q; p }'
```

Comment: I was thinking for the same. let me try it and if it works i will be greatly helpful :) thanks Seth and Levon

Comment: @MohitKumar Along the same lines as above, I first tried using FS but w/o luck. More info about the data could possibly yield alternate solutions (I just came up with one, but again, it depends on knowing more about the data :)

Comment: Yeah , the above solution works fine , but I have another problem ( excuse me as I am bit new with it) i have the following output, if I use the above awk i have an output  
NodeID> Command1
data
NodeID> Command1
data
how can i select the last output?

Comment: @MohitKumar: `awk 'BEGIN { RS="NODE-ID> "; } /^command1/ { foo=RS $0; } END { print foo; }'`  Perl would be fairly similar.  I wouldn't care to try that in sed

Answer (score 1):

#### A Sed Solution

It is certainly possible to do this with sed. For example, this command returns the subsequent output:

```
$ sed -n '/command1/,/command2/ { /command2/q; p }' /tmp/foo
```

> NODE-ID> command1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Comment: I needed to add a `;` after the `p` to get this to work, but it works.

Comment: I think if you included "^NODE-ID> " in the regular expressions it would be much more protected against the vagaries of the input data.

Comment: @SethRobertson It's much harder to construct a range expression that way with sed, such that it matches the second NODE-ID *and* excludes it from output. It can be done, but it's a lot more work. I'd certainly upvote a more comprehensive sed expression if you want to write one.

Comment: @mVChr I'm not sure why you would need the extra semi-colon with a properly-quoted expression. However, I'm using GNU sed 4.2.1 and Bash 4.2.10; if you're using something else that might possibly make a difference.

Comment: What are you talking about?  This works fine:  `sed -n '/^NODE-ID> command1/,/^NODE-ID> command2/ { /^NODE-ID> command2/q; p }'`

Comment: @SethRobertson Try `/^NODE/,/^NODE/` to see what I mean. Given your corpus, there's no need for a more exact expression than the one provided in my answer--it works fine against Lorem Ipsum. However, you should certainly feel free to adapt *any* Stack Overflow answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, being fully generic so that you don't need to specify the name of the command after the command in question requires more work.  This wasn't my original intent (I was just concerned with the string "command2" appearing in command1's output), but inspired by you I did so and added it to my answer.  It is probably more verbose than it needs to be but I'm not familiar enough with sed to compact it.

Comment: thanks for the comment @CodeGnome but my problem is its not always the same commands in sequence so i cannot extract the data between two consequent commands.

Answer (score 0):

If there was something unique in your last line of your records, such the string "consequat" in your sample data this *simple* `awk` command would work:

```
awk '/command2/,/consequat/ {print $0}' data.txt
```

Alternatively, if the length of the records is going to be the same, then this will work:

```
awk '/command2/{st=NR;for(i=st;i<=st+6;i++){print $0;getline}}' data.txt
```

In this example it will extract the block starting with `command2` and grab the next 6 lines (which works with the provided sample data set/format)

Comment: no , the length of data is never the same , infact thats the biggest problem, but thanks for the solution , the RS method in awk works..

Comment: @MohitKumar is there something you can be sure of at the end of each record? In that case the first simple solution in my answer will work just fine. In any case, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: No, the end of each record is different , Thanks @Levon

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/NODE-ID> command1/!d;n;n;:a;/./!Q;n;ba' file
```

or:

```
sed '/NODE-ID> command1/!d;n;n;q' file
```

if the command only consists of one line of text (as per your example).